# How can I make the trigger wait?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers, for-xml-path

I have a problem that I can not solve, I have a point of sale that inserts 3 tables after selling something, the header table, detail and customers (in that order).

I have a stored procedure that inserts the last record in the bak table, in the "text" column it inserts a concatenated of the 3 tables (it is fundamental), at the same time I have a stuff method that gathers all the details in a single row with the corresponding header (only one row per header), when executing the procedure after inserting it works normally, but when doing it with a trigger, an error appears that a null value can not be inserted in the "text" column, this is because the trigger points to the table header and the other 2 tables to a do not fill, if I put it at the level of detail, the stuff method does not work(since it inserts one record per header), the idea is to point to the header table but wait until everything is completed, there is some way to do it? I can not touch anything from the point of sale, everything would be at the database level (SQL SERVER 2008), can something be done? Can the trigger be delayed so that it waits for the completion of the filling of the other 2 tables?

**--INTERMEDIATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE [bak]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [serie] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [text] [varchar](6000) NOT NULL
);
```

**--STORE PROCEDURE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_bak
AS
BEGIN
  ;
  WITH CTE
  AS (SELECT
    h.date InsertDate,
    h.series DocumentSerie,
    ('349891894' + h.date + h.series + h.total +
    h.type + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) HeaderData,
    (d.quantity + d.price + d.description + c.name + 
    c.identification) DetailData
  FROM header h
  FULL JOIN detail d
    ON a.cod = b.cod
  FULL JOIN customers c
    ON b.cod = c.cod)
  INSERT dbo.bak (date, serie, text)
    SELECT TOP 1
      InsertDate,
      DocumentSerie,
      HeaderData + REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT
        ';' + DetailData
      FROM CTE C
      WHERE C.HeaderData = T.HeaderData
      FOR xml PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''), ';', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
    FROM CTE T
    GROUP BY HeaderData,
             DocumentSerie,
             InsertDate
  order by InsertDate DESC
END
```

**--TRIGGER**

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_bak
ON dbo.header
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_bak
END
GO
```

**--ERROR**

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_bak, Line 4
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'text', table 'VIDEOJUEGOS.dbo.bak'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Comment: Your logic doesn't make any sense to me at all but to answer your question, no. A trigger fires synchronously. Anything you did to make it wait would just delay how long before your error is raised. A slight detour, the sp_ prefix is not a good habit. You should either change your prefix, or even better have no prefix at all. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix Can you put the trigger on the last table?

Comment: Also, your trigger is not referencing either the inserted or deleted virtual tables. This is a huge red flag that something is not right in your trigger. Most likely you should be using inserted instead of that TOP 1 query.

Comment: My procedure is much bigger, I have reduced it to be able to better explain my doubt(it may be that something has moved, because the original if it works for me without using the trigger), on the subject of "sp_", if it was my mistake, I usually use "usp_", so I was taught at the institute. I was afraid that I was not going to see solution for this, hopefully later add an option in sql server, like the string_agg that they added in sql-server 2017 to impersonate the stuff xml path, well I'll have to do it with a job nothing else, thank you very much. I don't speak english, sorry.

Comment: OK so taking the trigger at face value and saying it is an example I still don't understand what you are really trying to do. Why can't you put the trigger on the last of the tables that get inserted? You would then have rows in the other two tables. You can't reference a row in this trigger that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

**What I understand is:** you have data coming into three tables and only after three tables have got the data, you have to insert data into BAK table. You dont have control over the when data will be coming to three tables.

I would suggest you below approaches:

- **Have a batch stored procedure:** which is scheduled on regular basis and does these kinds of batch insertion. You can have a date filter for only picking the values, which got inserted after the previous run
- **Disclaimer: This is a bad approach of using triggers.** You need to defined three triggers in three tables. Always check for the existence of records in all the three tables and generate header. If header value is NOT NULL then insert into the BAK table. So, here BAK table insert can come through any of the three triggers.

Answer (score -1):

In your stored procedure for sp_bak, you can have the first statement as:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
```

The time can be any number of seconds, but enough till the other tables gets inserted with values. The above statements delays the execution of the statements following the WAITFOR by 5 seconds.
Be aware, this might not be a good way to handle this kind of issue, because if the delay time is too high, the trigger might take time to execute and cause a delay of operations.

Comment: How is this going to help? That procedure runs from the trigger on that table. All this will do is add 5 seconds before the same error occurs.

Comment: While the stored procedure waits, the values would be inserted in the detail and customers table, and the statements in the stored procedure would return values from those tables as required.

Comment: No that won't happen like that. When they insert in bak the trigger will fire which will call this procedure. Triggers are not asynchronous so the other inserts in the original code will be waiting for the insert to finish. And that insert is waiting for the trigger to complete. All of that is required for the atomic part of ACID.

Comment: Kashyap MNVL, I had already tried that, as Sean Lange said, that does not work, the only thing he does is delay the error.